# Fails to paint within QGLWidget

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a weird issue with OpenGL in Qt. I have a derived class from QGLWidget. I use `makeCurrent()` in `initializeGL` because I need to call some OpenGL functions first. The OpenGL widget is embedded into a QFrame.

When I run the application in QtCreator, it perfectly runs. When I run it as a *standalone* one, the OpenGL surface seems not to update at all.

Any clue?

EDIT: the problem seems to come with `optirun`…

Comment: This probably won't help with your problem, but do you know about the [initializeGL](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#initializeGL) function?  It was made specifically for the situation you're describing in the first paragraph.

Comment: yes I do, and it has actually nothing to do with the issue :) here the problem would rather be in `paintGL`, or `swapBuffers`